# How do I change the properties of a control within a list dynamically (C# Winform)?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a list of checkbox controls

`public List<CheckBox> _checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();`

I add a certain amount during runtime using a switch case with the properties such as location and visibility.

This all works fine, but if I want the checkboxes to disappear or become checked at some point the GUI doesn't get updated, the list is updated with the new data but just not visually.

*** I ended up doing this***
I created a bunch of checkboxes on the winfrom.Created a method which you can choose which ones are visible. Then created a method to fill a list of type checkbox. Then you can search the panel for control types, once you found the control, it can be manipulated.  This isn't elegant and probably isn't the best way, but i am new to custom controls and winforms.

```
//search panel for checkboxes
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
{
    if (c is CustomControls.RoundedCheckBox)
    {
        CustomControls.RoundedCheckBox checkBox = c as CustomControls.RoundedCheckBox;
        //if it is checked add to list
        if(checkBox.Checked)
        {
            _checkBoxes.Add(checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you update them then? I assume you try to find your checkbox first in the form Controls collection and then manipulate it?

Comment: Most likely the item in the list is not the same as the item on your form.  We'd need to see more code to diagnose this problem...

Answer (score -1):

If you have something like this:

```
_checkBoxes.Add(new CheckBox());
_checkBoxes[0].Parent = this;
```

then you should be able to manipulate your checkboxes from the list:

```
_checkBoxes[0].Checked = false;
```

But, the problem may occur if you do it in some kind of loop and want to see the results immediately.

In Windows there is something called message loop. Application simply works like that (pseudocode: TL;DR)

```
while(true)
{ 
    message = GetFirstMessage();
    if(message != null)
    {
        if(message.Id == CloseApplication)
            break;

        DispatchMessage(message);
        RemoveFirstMessage();
    }
}
```

So, application takes message from queue, then process it. A message is everything - button click, mouse move, paint... Everything.

So when a message is dispatched it looks for the control that should receive this message and then it does some work.

So, for example if you have something like that:

```
foreach(var ch in _checkBoxes)
{
    ch.Checked = false;
    DoSomeWorkThatTakesTime();
    ch.Checked = true;
}
```

You won't see the change, because you are "trapped" in DispatchMessage. When you set `Checked`, you really sending a message. But this message cannot be Dispatched right now, because you are inside the foreach loop.

So the only thing you can do here is to tell your application - now, please DO READ message queue. In WinForms it's called "DoEvents", so this will do the work:

```
foreach(var ch in _checkBoxes)
{
    ch.Checked = false;
    Application.DoEvents();

    DoSomeWorkThatTakesTime();

    ch.Checked = true;
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: "Why did I get vote down?"  My guess...any time any one on this site sees `DoEvents()`, they immediately downvote and somewhere on the planet a baby dies.